# Override vendor admin view.xml file Magento2

Tags: magento2

so i need to override this file **vendor/magento/module-page-builder/etc/view.xml**

i already tried doing it by copying it here:

> app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme/etc/view.xml

and it works! but only on the frontend.

i need the changes i made to reflect in admin as well, so i tried creating some folders with the same file here:

> app/design/adminhtml/My_Vendor/My_Theme/etc/view.xml

and then added the same **registration.php** and **theme.xml** files i found inside **app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/My_Theme** but it's not working.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you will find this article very helpful https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/create-admin/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below module.
It could be a good start point to solve your issue.

```
backup/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend
```

This is the default theme for the admin.
You can extend it in `app/design/adminhtml` as per your needs.
Just follow the same file structure in theme

Give it a try and let me know. If you need any further help. I'm around!